# Hide specific shipping methods for a specific user roles in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, shipping-method

In Woocommerce I am using WooCommerce Wholesale Pro Suite *(from IgniteWoo)* and Flat Rate Box Shipping plugins to add B2B to our eshop.

I am trying to disable the Flat Rate Box Shipping for specific user roles, guests and customers. I found this code after searching online:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_for_user_role', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_for_user_role( $rates, $package ) {
// Role ID to be excluded
$excluded_role = "wholesale_customer";

// Shipping rate to be excluded
$shipping_id = 'table_rate_shipping_free-shipping';

// Get current user's role
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( empty( $user ) ) return false;

if( in_array( $excluded_role, (array) $user->roles ) && isset( $rates[ $shipping_id ] ) )
unset( $rates[ $shipping_id ] );

return $rates;
}
```

What should I use in place of "`wholesale_customer`" and in place of "`table_rate_shipping_free-shipping`", so the Flat Rate Box Shipping is not showing, for guests and customers roles?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2:**

> You may have to "**Enable debug mode**" in general shipping settings under "**Shipping options**" tab, **to disable temporarily shipping caches.**

**For info:** The shipping method ID for "Flat rate boxes" is **`flat_rate_boxes`**.

The following code will disable "Flat rate boxes" Shipping Methods For "Guests" *(non logged in users)* and "customer" user role:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_method_based_on_user_role', 30, 2 );
function hide_specific_shipping_method_based_on_user_role( $rates, $package ) {

    ## --- Your settings --- ##
    $excluded_role = "customer"; // User role to be excluded
    $shipping_id = 'flat_rate_boxes'; // Shipping rate to be removed

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        if( $rate->method_id === $shipping_id ){
            if( current_user_can( $excluded_role ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ){
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Don't forget to enable back shipping cache.

Comment: Hi Guys, Can someone confirm if this still works in 2022? I'm trying to use it, but it seems to fail (flat rates do not disappear when not logged in).

Comment: I was totally ignoring this answer's comment about caching. But I found a link in the WC source code containing this hook to a WC snippet that disables shipping method cache: https://gist.github.com/woogists/271654709e1d27648546e83253c1a813

Comment: Also not to be a stickler but your snippet is using double quotes for "customer" and single quotes for "flat_rate_boxes"