# Enable shipping method for specific user role ONLY in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, shipping-method

I have been looking at lots of snippets to enable a shipping method for a specific user role only. So anyone who is NOT part of this user role should not see it, including guests who are not logged in.

The snippets like below don't achieve this and I am struggling to reverse the logic. I want to avoid having to manually input every shipping method to the snippet, which is obviously not future proof due to when new shipping methods are added.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_specific_shipping_method_based_on_user_role', 100, 2 );
function hide_specific_shipping_method_based_on_user_role( $rates, $package ) {
    // Here define the shipping rate ID to hide
    $targeted_rate_id    = '15'; // The shipping rate ID to hide
    $targeted_user_roles = array('clubadmin');  // The user roles to target (array)

    $current_user  = wp_get_current_user();
    $matched_roles = array_intersect($targeted_user_roles, $current_user->roles);

    if( ! empty($matched_roles) && isset($rates[$targeted_rate_id]) ) {
        unset($rates[$targeted_rate_id]);
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Original Post: [Woocommerce Shipping method based on user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671392/woocommerce-shipping-method-based-on-user-role)

Author: [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, this shipping method should be disabled, unless the user fulfills a certain user role

In the `$rate_ids` array you add 1 or more IDs for the respective shipping methods

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Set the rate IDs in the array
    $rate_ids = array( 'local_pickup:1', 'free_shipping:2' );
    
    // NOT the required user role, remove shipping method(s)
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        // Loop trough
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            // Checks if a value exists in an array
            if ( in_array( $rate_id, $rate_ids ) ) {
                unset( $rates[$rate_id] );
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

---

**Note:** to find the correct `$rate_ids` you can use the second part from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72089957/11987538) - (The "for debugging purposes" part)

Comment: Perfect! Tested and works. Interesting as I have not seen "current_user_can" used before. This helps a lot! Thanks.